Fragments overlap on screen orientation change
I am in the process of learning fragments. I am trying to create a simple App with a list of country names in one fragment and some information about the country in another fragment.
In the onCreate() method of the main activity, I first add the list fragment and then I observe for change in the mutable data using the view model and if a change is made, I add the information fragment.
My onCreate Code:
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   addCountriesFragment();

   viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ListItemViewModel.class);
   viewModel.getListItemPicked().observe(this, state -> {
      addCountryDescriptionFragment(state);
   });
}

The code inside addCountriesFragment():
private void addCountriesFragment(){
   fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   CountriesFragment countriesFragment = new CountriesFragment();
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, countriesFragment);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

The code inside addCountryDescriptionFragment():
private void addCountryDescriptionFragment(int index){
   fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   CountryDescriptionFragment countryDescriptionFragment = new CountryDescriptionFragment();
   Bundle args = new Bundle();
   args.putInt("itemIndex", index);
   countryDescriptionFragment.setArguments(args);
   fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, countryDescriptionFragment);
   fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

This is my xml file for the main activity:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer" />
    >

</LinearLayout>


I have set up a ViewModel which allows information about the country to be shown when a list item in clicked. I will now provide a series of steps that lead to the issue as mentioned in the title.

App opens with fragment containing list displayed.
I click on a list item. List fragment gets replaced by the information fragment.
I change orientation from portrait to landscape. The information fragment gets displayed because of the way the app is set up.
When I click on the back button, I see the list and information fragment at the same time overlapping. Then I press back again, and the overlap disappears.


I do not understand why this is happening. Any tip or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

your activity gets recreated when you rotate the screen , so oncreate is being called again .

yes, onCreate() is being called again, so both the fragments are being created again. But why would that cause the overlapping?

Because you're calling add. 1st Pass you add a new fragment. 2nd pass system recreates the first fragment, then you add a second fragment. Add a null check to your logic if (savedInstanceState == null) addCountries()

I am using replace for the second fragment not add.

See my answer and explanation.


I do not understand why this is happening. Any tip or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Why: The Android system attempts to automatically restore fragments on restoring state (like an orientation change). To prevent conflicting with this behavior you should only be adding / replacing fragments when there is no state (see documentation).
What is happening:

You add a fragment to the container:
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, countriesFragment);.


You have a stack of one fragment.

You replace it with a description and add to the backstack:
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, countryDescriptionFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);



You now have a stack of two fragments.

You change orientation. The system preserves the current set of fragments for you, so you still have a stack of two fragments.
Because you do not check for savedInstanceState being null, you add another countries fragment (causing your overlap), and then you replace another description fragment, causing "The information fragment gets displayed because of the way the app is set up.", as you observed.

You now have a stack 4 fragments, in 3 layers: Countries -> Countries + Description -> Description.

Thus, when you press back you see the overlap, and when you press back again, you see countries:


When I click on the back button, I see the list and information fragment at the same time overlapping. Then I press back again, and the overlap disappears.

How to fix this: always check for savedInstanceState == null when adding fragments in onCreate.
https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-programmatic
